# Favicon not Showing on Jekyll Site

Tags: html, jekyll

I have been trying to set up a Favicon for a GitHub Pages site using Jekyll. However, even when setting the right tags in the HTML *head*, it still doesn't show. I have tried using:

```
<link rel="icon" href="{{ site.baseurl }}/favicon.png" type="image/png">
```

and the usual:

```
<link rel="icon" href="./favicon.png" type="image/x-icon">
```

and all the variations with and without `{{ site.baseurl }}`, and with either PNG and ICO images (256x256 and 16x16 respectively) and their respective HTM *link* tag `type`s. Clearing the cache does not work, either.

The relevant part of the HTML file is as follows:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"><!-- Begin Jekyll SEO tag v2.7.1 -->
<title>EZCompile PHP</title>
<meta name="generator" content="Jekyll v4.1.1" />
<link rel="icon" href="./favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
<meta property="og:title" content="Your awesome title" />
<meta property="og:locale" content="en_US" />
<meta name="description" content="The Easy way to compile and install PHP and MySQL on MacOS, Windows, and Linux." />
<meta property="og:description" content="The Easy way to compile and install PHP and MySQL on MacOS, Windows, and Linux." />
<link rel="canonical" href="https://one-and-only.github.io/EZCompile-PHP/" />
<meta property="og:url" content="https://one-and-only.github.io/EZCompile-PHP/" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="EZCompile PHP" />
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary" />
<meta property="twitter:title" content="EZCompile PHP" />
<script type="application/ld+json">
{"url":"https://one-and-only.github.io/EZCompile-PHP/","name":"EZCompile PHP","headline":"EZCompile PHP","description":"The Easy way to compile and install PHP and MySQL on MacOS, Windows, and Linux.","@type":"WebSite","@context":"https://schema.org"}</script>
<!-- Integrate Bootstrap -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
```

The relevant part of the `_config.yml` file is as follows:

```
title: "EZCompile PHP"
email: 'email@gmail.com'
author: "name"
baseurl: "" # the subpath of your site, e.g. /blog
url: "" # the base hostname & protocol for your site, e.g. http://example.com
github_username:  one-and-only
plugins:
    - jekyll-seo-tag
```

I have navigated to the path of the image given in the *link* tag and it does indeed exist. No errors exist in the console, either.

### EDIT:

The GitHub Pages site is not up to date. It is hosted under localhost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I notice that when specifying the favicon, you use a path relative to the current directory:

```
<link rel="icon" href="./favicon.png" type="image/x-icon">
```

I use Jekyll with the Liquid filter [relative_url](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/liquid/filters/) for the path above, which safely returns a path that is relative to the domain root:

```
<link rel="icon" href="{{ "./favicon.png" | relative_url }}" type="image/x-icon">
```

which will return the path "/favicon.png" (and also works when baseurl is set).

There may be other issues with your specification of the favicon. I have used [realfavicongenerator.net](https://realfavicongenerator.net/) (introduced in some detail [here](https://css-tricks.com/favicon-quiz/)) to help me correctly specify my site's favicon for various situations, with very good results.

Comment: This totally worked, thanks so much! FWIW this is mine:


<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="{{ "assets/favicon-32x32.png" | relative_url }}">